# Javascript OOP library for client and server-side js (node.js)

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

is there any Javascript OOP library to easily work with classes, inherence and the like in a more class-based way to avoid prototypical OOP that works with JS both on the client (browser) and on the server (in my case Node.js, but generally that uses javascript core functions, so that can be used no matter the interpreter)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Rightjs](http://rightjs.org/) library has a server build [you can download](http://rightjs.org/download).

I think it has Node.js specifically in mind.

*From the download page:*

> RightJS is also available as a server-side library. In this case it contains only the native JavaScript unit extensions and the Class, Observer, Options units along with all the non-DOM utility functions from the Util module.
>
> Our server-side build follows the CommonJS principles and is ready for use with the node.js framework.

Answer (score 2):

Check out

- [qxoo from Qooxdoo](http://news.qooxdoo.org/download-qxoo-now)
- [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I just released https://github.com/alessioalex/Cls 3 days ago. It's very lightweight, has 3 functions under the hood (a mixin function to copy properties, a extends function for inheritance and the Cls function that parses the arguments and uses the previous two).

This works for Node.js & the browser and I've tried my best to document & test it well.

An example of the syntax:

```
var Person = Cls({
  methods: {
    constructor: function(name, age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    },
    present: function(otherDude) {
      return "Hello " + otherDude + " I'm " + this.name + ", my age is: " + this.age;
    }
  },
});

var Student = Cls({
  // extends the Person class
  uber: Person,
  present: function() {
    /**
     * call super function
     * note that this approach works even async (unlike other class libs)
     */
    return this.inherited('present', arguments);
  }
});

/**
 * since the constructor is missing
 * it will call the super constructor automatically
 */
var alex = new Student('Alex', 25);
alex.present();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple days ago, Dirk Ginader, frontend enginner at Yahoo!, told me that the latest release of [YUI3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) works flawlessly with node.js.

I haven't verified that myself (not a big fan of YUI) but Dirk is working at the Yahoo! mail application whose next release will be (partially) based on node.js. That's good enough for me to believe that he knew what he was talking about :-)